# Check/Uncheck Boxes From a Dynamic Range Based On Condition

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a to-do list with checkboxes for my employees in a spreadsheet with a dynamic number of rows that cannot exceed row 20. Because starting from row 20  another employee's to-do list is available.

I have a checkbox next to the name of the employee. Once I check/uncheck that checkbox, I want all below checkboxes to check or uncheck no matter how many rows are added or removed as long as it does not pass row number 20.

I have therefore named the range on row 20 so that even if it moves, apps script can locate it through named range. I have removed the named range and called it instead ('A20') in the script below to avoid confusion.

I thought a forloop could work but I must be doing something wrong because it is executing successfully but showing no results.

```
    function Todolist() {

     var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
     var lianrange = spreadsheet.getRange('A20');
 
    for (var i = 1 ; i<lianrange.length;i++){
    if (spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getValue() === 'check'){

     spreadsheet.getRange[i].setValue('Y');
    }

     if (spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getValue() === 'uncheck'){

     spreadsheet.getRange[i].setValue('N');     
    }
 }

 };
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check or uncheckall

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Entry');
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const rg = sh.getRange('stopRow');//stopRow is name of namedRange
  const sr = rg.getRow();
  //need to update name of sheet
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.rowStart < sr) {
    //e.source.toast('Gate1');
    const vs = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnStart, sr - e.range.rowStart + 1).getValues().flat();
    const cv = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnStart).getValue();
    let o = vs.map((e, i) => [cv])
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnStart, o.length).setValues(o);
  }
}
```

demo:

[image]

Comment: Hi Cooper and thank you for your answer. Could you please tell me what "e" in "e.range.getSheet();" stands for ? also is "range" a variable ?

Comment: e is the parameter that holds the event object which is populated by the onEdit trigger which fires whenever someone makes an edit to the spreadsheet